# embeding and itegrate Flash movie in WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, flash

I know that my question has been asked before but I didn't found any answer suitable for my case or even works.
My problem is: I need to embed a Flash movie inside WPF application, then I need to use Externalinterface - or whatever the way is - to integrate through this flash movie - I'm working on Visual Studio 2008!
I found some ways but no one worked with me ... sadly.

can you help do this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` to present a webpage with your Flash on it. Then you'd use JavaScript to communicate with Flash via ExternalInterface and back to WPF through `window.external` which is actually the `ObjectForScripting` property on the `WebBrowser` control.